# How to integrate box squat to my weekly leg workout

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, squats

I'm usually free squatting (8x) and leg pressing (4x)

For a change, and also to see whether I can improve 1-my hip flexors and 2- the bottom part of my squat, I want to include 4x box squatting, (with wide stance, if you wondered) instead of 4x regular squat, having at the end 4x of each method.

Should I do the 4x standard squat first or 4x box squatting first?

I would tend to fatigue my hips first to later emphasise the quads by starting with the box squat, but I'm not so sure.

What do you think? Thank you.

PS: my current workout plan is a 4days per week routine:

- D1: shoulder back [push press, chinups ...]
- D2: glutes quads calves [squat, press ...]
- D3: chest biceps [bench press, curls ...]
- D4: hamstrings triceps [deadlift, dips ...]

I can't really do more.

Comment: Not quite sure what the rest of your week looks like, but I would do the following: normal squat day 1 + day 2, then box squat day 3. In fact, I would dedicate the entire day 3 to explosive or power movements.

Comment: yeah, I'm basically running a 4days split routine: d1 push press + back; d2: quads glutes and calves; d3: chest and biceps; d4: deadlift and triceps; I don't have time for a fifth day, but that'd be great...

Comment: Could you incorporate that schedule into your question?

Comment: So, I just finished quads day, starting by the box is really cool because you have all the explosivity you need to focus on the hips. I don't think I could do so starting by standard squat. Waiting for more opinions.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "standard squats" are you implying ATG (ass to grass)?  Full range of motion is important in all lifts.  Box squats are a great way to make sure you're going to depth.  Don't do "standard" AND box, just do box squats to make sure you're getting parallel.

Comment: my "standard squats" are athletics - low bar positionned. It means the stance of my leg and the bar don't allow me to touch the ground, but I go as deep as my hamstrings can.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a little feedback: I did that for 4 weeks, and realised I took no interest from it because my posterior chain *was already my strong point*

I'm using a different approach now, doing 4x athletic squats + 4x front squats, and my quadriceps have much better sensations (not mentionning the fact that my back really LOVES the front squat!)

Cheers,
S.